# append code after the_content not working

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, filters, the-content

**Goal:**

Add pagination below single post pages.

**Code**

```
function add_pagin( $content ) {
    if ( is_singular('post') ) {
        $content .= previous_post_link() . next_post_link();
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_pagin' );
```

**Result**

Pagination added to the top of `the_content`, not below it. If I change `$content.=` to echo a simple string it works, but not with those two wprdpress functions.

I appreciate the help with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`previous_post_link` and `next_post_link` both output the link directly, which won't work in your case because you're trying to assign the result to a variable. Use `get_previous_post_link()` and `get_next_post_link()` instead-

```
function add_pagin( $content ) {
    if ( is_singular('post') ) {
        $content .= get_previous_post_link() . get_next_post_link();
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_pagin' );
```